# Limit Exception: Too many SOQL queries

Tags: triggers, salesforce, limit, apex

I'm receiving an exception when I try to use data loader for this apex trigger. It says there's limit of 100 records to be updated at a time. Here is the code that explains a trigger on Account Object. All the comments are much appreciated

```
trigger MaintainPrimaryOverriding on Account (before insert, before update) {

    if (TriggerUpdateController.getPrimaryBranchOverriding()){

         TriggerAffiliationControl.setLock();


  for(Account s : Trigger.new)
    {

   if (Trigger.isUpdate){ 
          Id ownerId =  Trigger.oldMap.get(s.Id).OwnerId;
        if (s.OwnerId != ownerId){
            //Use Branch Associated with owner ID
            TriggerUpdateController.UpdatePrimaryBranchOfficeForAccountOwnerChange(s);
            TriggerUpdateController.UpdateAffiliation(s);         
          }
   }
    else if(Trigger.isInsert){ 

          TriggerUpdateController.UpdatePrimaryBranchOfficeForAccountOwnerChange(s);

    }
  }
           TriggerAffiliationControl.setUnLock();

 }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error **Too many SOQL queries** is due to the fact, you are hitting on governor limit. Look at [Best Practice: Avoid SOQL Queries Inside FOR Loops](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3a_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling below methods in your code for each update/insert record

"TriggerUpdateController.UpdatePrimaryBranchOfficeForAccountOwnerChange(s)"
"TriggerUpdateController.UpdateAffiliation(s)"

Looks like you are issuing SOQL statement in those above statements, which causing the governing limit error.

two modifications you have to do here.
1. Capture the list of updated or inserted accounts in a list and pass them to above two methods.
2. make above two methods to accept the list of accounts created in step1 and do the processing.
3. If you want fetch details from some other object, get those details in a SOQL.

If you could post the code for "TriggerUpdateController", i would be in a better position to suggest you correct code.

Regards,
Pundareekam Kudikala